# Should I remove the leading "0" when sending PHP array to JSON?

Tags: javascript, php, chart.js

My project is to create a bar chart with "Chart.Js".

The chart should show records based on all weeks in a year. The data comes from a datetime column in MySQL.

**This is how I do it:**
First my select in MySQL:

```php
$query = "SELECT datetime_start FROM table WHERE datetime_start LIKE '2020%' ORDER BY datetime_start ASC";
```

Now I have records like: 2020-03-12 09:38:00

To group the dates into weeks I do this:

```
while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
    
    $date = new DateTime($row['datetime_start']);
    $week = $date->format("W");
    
    $data[$week]++;
}
```

And from this I send it to JS with: `echo json_encode($data);`

In the JS I do a `console.log(result)` and I get a list where the key represent the week and the value is how many dates I have in that week.

This is where my problem occurs!
The list is sorted:

```
{10: 42, 11: 40, 12: 40, 13: 44, 14: 26, 15: 33, 16: 27, 17: 31, 18: 21, 19: 21, 20: 20, 21: 22, 22: 25, 23: 22, 24: 19, 25: 7, 26: 9, 27: 6, 28: 1, 29: 6, 30: 5, 31: 7, 32: 1, 33: 5, 34: 5, 35: 6, 36: 4, 37: 2, 38: 2, 39: 4, 40: 2, 41: 3, 42: 2, 43: 3, 44: 3, 45: 3, 46: 2, 47: 2, 48: 6, 49: 4, 50: 4, 51: 2, 52: 2, 53: 1, 01: 23, 02: 25, 03: 34, 04: 43, 05: 31, …}
```

Week 10 comes before week 01. And this will result in my chart looking like this:

[image]

**Which way is the best to solve this?**

I have checked the Php.net for a datetime object that doesn't have a leading zero in the week number (`format('w')`), but it doesn't exist.

Should I remove the leading zero with PHP or JS to solve this? I think the PHP array is correct starting with 01, but when I decode it to JSON, the order changes and 10 will be the first key in the object?!

**EDIT**

My PHP looks fine:

```
Array ( [01] => 23 [02] => 25 [03] => 34 [04] => 43 [05] => 31 [06] => 37 [07] => 32 [08] => 34 [09] => 45 [10] => 42 [11] => 40 [12] => 40 [13] => 44 [14] => 26 [15] => 33 [16] => 27 [17] => 31 [18] => 21 [19] => 21 [20] => 20 [21] => 22 [22] => 25 [23] => 22 [24] => 19 [25] => 7 [26] => 9 [27] => 6 [28] => 1 [29] => 6 [30] => 5 [31] => 7 [32] => 1 [33] => 5 [34] => 5 [35] => 6 [36] => 4 [37] => 2 [38] => 2 [39] => 4 [40] => 2 [41] => 3 [42] => 2 [43] => 3 [44] => 3 [45] => 3 [46] => 2 [47] => 2 [48] => 6 [49] => 4 [50] => 4 [51] => 2 [52] => 2 [53] => 1 )
```

It's the JSON that gets messy:

```
{10: 42, 11: 40, 12: 40, 13: 44, 14: 26, 15: 33, 16: 27, 17: 31, 18: 21, 19: 21, 20: 20, 21: 22,…}
```

Comment: `ksort([YOUR_ARRAY])` should work here. It will order the keys 1 to n. [see more](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php). Update: `ksort()` returns a boolean, not the sorted array. This should be done before passing it through `json_encode()` on a single line.

Comment: JSON maintains the order in which your array was sorted, so the proposed solutions will solve your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use an associative array, use an indexed array. Start by creating an array with 53 elements, then update it in the loop.

```
$data = array_fill(0, 53, 0);
while($row = $stmt->fetch()){

    $date = new DateTime($row['datetime_start']);
    $week = $date->format("W");

    $data[intval($week)]++;
}
```

Comment: This did not change anything. The problem still accour when i decode the array to json. It changes from 01, 02.. to 10, 11...01,02

Comment: I changed my answer

Comment: Now i have both 0 and 01 in my json: {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 0, 9: 0, 10: 42, 11: 40, 12: 40, 13: 44, 14: 26, 15: 33, 16: 27, 17: 31, 18: 21, 19: 21, 20: 20, 21: 22, 22: 25, 23: 22, 24: 19, 25: 7, 26: 9, 27: 6, 28: 1, 29: 6, 30: 5, 31: 7, 32: 1, 33: 5, 34: 5, 35: 6, 36: 4, 37: 2, 38: 2, 39: 4, 40: 2, 41: 3, 42: 2, 43: 3, 44: 3, 45: 3, 46: 2, 47: 2, 48: 6, 49: 4, 50: 4, 51: 2, 52: 2, 53: 1, 01: 23, 02: 25, 03: 34, 04: 43, 05: 31, …}

Comment: And my array: Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 0 [2] => 0 [3] => 0 [4] => 0 [5] => 0 [6] => 0 [7] => 0 [8] => 0 [9] => 0 [10]  => 6 [30] => 5 [31] => 7 [32] => 1 [33] => 5 [34] => 5 [35] => 6 [36] => 4 [37] => 2 [38] => 2 [39] => 4 [40] => 2 [41] => 3 [42] => 2 [43] => 3 [44] => 3 [45] => 3 [46] => 2 [47] => 2 [48] => 6 [49] => 4 [50] => 4 [51] => 2 [52] => 2 [01] => 23 [02] => 25 [03] => 34 [04] => 43 [05] => 31 [06] => 37 [07] => 32 [08] => 34 [09] => 45 [53] => 1 )

Comment: The datetime object "format("W") creates 01, and the array_fill creates 0, 1, 2 ...

Comment: `intval($week)` should convert `01` to `1`.

Comment: I missed the last update with intval! Now its working: [0, 23, 25, 34, 43, 31, 37, 32, 34, 45, 42, 40, 40, 44, 26, 33, 27, 31, 21, 21, 20, 22, 25, 22, 19, 7,…] Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Since JSON keeps the same array structure as the predecessor, you can sort the array into order prior to translating it to JSON.

```
ksort($data); // Add this before
json_encode($data); // This line
```

`ksort()` returns a boolean, thus it must be declared as its own statement prior to using `json_encode()`.

[See a working demo here](https://3v4l.org/RRnIj).

Comment: With the new php from Bamar, and yours.. i get this: Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 0 [2] => 0 [3] => 0 [4] => 0 [5] => 0 [6] => 0 [7] => 0 [8] => 0 [9] => 0 [10] => 42 [11] => 40 [12] => 40 [13] => 44 [14] => 26 [15] => 33 [16] => 27 [17] => 31 [18] => 2 [49] => 4 [50] => 4 [51] => 2 [52] => 2 [01] => 23 [02] => 25 [03] => 34 [04] => 43 [05] => 31 [06] => 37 [07] => 32 [08] => 34 [09] => 45 [53] => 1 )

Comment: You're using Array fill, indexs in arrays start at 0 thus it will fill before the starting index of 1 you seek. Your code had no issues before. Just keep what you had but add `ksort()` before you use the `json_encode()` if you want this solution to work.